# jquery on() Proxy context unexpected

Tags: jquery, proxy

This my code, basically, when tags_delete is clicked I would like to access id of the parent div. Somehow the context is not picked up. I have read the examples of $.proxy but can't get it to work.

```
<div class="text">
<div id="894" class="tags">
<img height="24" src="image">
<a class="tags_delete"></a>
</div>
<input id="tag_list" type="text">
</div>

$("div.text").on("click", "a.tags_delete",          
                $.proxy(function(that){                     
                    var imageId = that.parent("div").prop("id");        
                    console.log(that); 
                    console.log( imageId );
                    this.deleteTag(imageId);
                }, this, $(this) )
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is since you have used [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), `this` inside the handler does not refer to the clicked element, so you can use the [event.currentTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) property to refer to the current target element and use [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to access its id

```
$("div.text").on("click", "a.tags_delete", $.proxy(function (e) {
    var imageId = $(e.currentTarget).parent().attr('id');
    console.log(that);
    console.log(imageId);
    this.deleteTag(imageId);
}, this));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vph5q/)

Comment: This works Arun, thanks ! Other contributions thanks too, but have to use proxy because of object setup.

Comment: @Bart next time provide the context in which you are setting your code, in question...

Comment: I will, apologies for the lack of info

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get parent id just use `parent()` function
[Here my fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/KB7wx/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
   {
       $("a.tags_delete").on("click",function(){         
           alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
        });
 });
```

Comment: what about `this.deleteTag(imageId)`?